# How to use deferred with loops

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I have a question: I have a function that allows me to display a few messages, one after another.

My code:

```
function showMessage(message) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  $("#message").text(message);
  $("#message").show();

  function dismissMessage() {
    $("#message").hide(deferred.resolve);
  }

  $("#message").one("click", function() {
    dismissMessage();
  });

  return deferred.promise();
}
```

And I can display messages with:

```
  showMessage("This is a message").then(function() {
    showMessage("This is another message").then(function() {
      showMessage("And this is yet another message");
    });
  });
```

My question is, how can I display a long list of messages, that I have stored in i.e. array, like:

```
var messages = ["This is a message", "This is another message", "And this is yet another message"];
```

Using a loop? I don't want to stack code.

Comment: Do want to show them sequentially from the array? ... if so, without jquery, you could use javscript's map() function after your array:  `messages.map(alert);` Each message will appear sequentially after the other.

Comment: How much time do you want from displaying one message to the next?

Comment: I think you need to create a promise for each. Defer, display message, click, resolve and go into the next loop.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but none of them really helps me. I'd like to keep my original code or change it, but in a way that I can still display messages in a <div>, one after another.